# C# library to populate object with random data

Tags: c#

I want to populate my object with random data (for testing purposes), is there a library to do it?

Some kind of reflection method that will traverse object graph and initialize primitive properties like (string, int, DateTime, etc) (but do it the deep way, including collections, child objects, etc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any tools to populate class properties with random data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413342/are-there-any-tools-to-populate-class-properties-with-random-data)

Comment: Have a look at this question too. It might not be a good thing to use random data only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317747/should-i-use-real-or-sample-data-for-unit-tests

Answer (score 67, accepted):

#### [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus)

[**Bogus**](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) is a simple and sane fake data generator for C# and .NET. A C# port of [faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) and inspired by FluentValidation's syntax sugar. *Supports **.NET Core**.*

**Setup**

```
public enum Gender
{
   Male,
   Female
}

var userIds = 0;

var testUsers = new Faker<User>()
    //Optional: Call for objects that have complex initialization
    .CustomInstantiator(f => new User(userIds++, f.Random.Replace("###-##-####")))

    //Basic rules using built-in generators
    .RuleFor(u => u.FirstName, f => f.Name.FirstName())
    .RuleFor(u => u.LastName, f => f.Name.LastName())
    .RuleFor(u => u.Avatar, f => f.Internet.Avatar())
    .RuleFor(u => u.UserName, (f, u) => f.Internet.UserName(u.FirstName, u.LastName))
    .RuleFor(u => u.Email, (f, u) => f.Internet.Email(u.FirstName, u.LastName))
    //Use an enum outside scope.
    .RuleFor(u => u.Gender, f => f.PickRandom<Gender>())
    //Use a method outside scope.
    .RuleFor(u => u.CartId, f => Guid.NewGuid());
```

**Generate**

```
var user = testUsers.Generate();
Console.WriteLine(user.DumpAsJson());

/* OUTPUT:
{
  "Id": 0,
  "FirstName": "Audrey",
  "LastName": "Spencer",
  "FullName": "Audrey Spencer",
  "UserName": "Audrey_Spencer72",
  "Email": "Audrey82@gmail.com",
  "Avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/itstotallyamy/128.jpg",
  "Gender": 0,
  "CartId": "863f9462-5b88-471f-b833-991d68db8c93", ....
```

**Without Fluent Syntax**

```
  public void Without_Fluent_Syntax()
  {
      var random = new Bogus.Randomizer();
      var lorem = new Bogus.DataSets.Lorem();
      var o = new Order()
          {
              OrderId = random.Number(1, 100),
              Item = lorem.Sentence(),
              Quantity = random.Number(1, 10)
          };
      o.Dump();
  }
  /* OUTPUT:
  {
    "OrderId": 61,
    "Item": "vel est ipsa",
    "Quantity": 7
  } */
```

Comment: I couldn't find an easy way to create a populated object without creating a rule for every property. AutoFixture worked best for me

Comment: @Vdex AutoBogus can populate objects without having to specify rules for every property: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoBogus/

Comment: Having access to domain specific rules that generate very relevant mocks is a huge plus for me.

Answer (score 29):

[NBuilder](https://github.com/nbuilder/nbuilder) is a very good fluent-API library for generating data. It uses rules that you define and isn't "random" per se. You may be able to randomize the inputs to the API, though, to suit your needs.

Since this still gets some attention I think it's worth mentioning the project is now available through NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NBuilder/) as well, though it hasn't been modified since 2011.

Answer (score 28):

I tried AutoFixture (https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) and it worked for me very well. 
It can easilty generate an object with a deep hierarchy of children in one line of code.

Comment: This is really good!

Answer (score 9):

I've recently been working on one that is exactly like what you described (maybe it's been done before but this seemed like a fun project to try). It is still a work in progress but I think it captures all the features you mentioned. You can find the Nuget package here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/randomtestvalues

And the repository here: https://github.com/RasicN/random-test-values

I hope you like it.

Example code:

`var randomMyClass = RandomValue.Object<MyClass>();`

Comment: I found this helpful. You can use [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture).

Answer (score 4):

[AutoPoco](http://autopoco.codeplex.com/) has some of that functionality, it doesn't do it with reflection, you tell it what type of data to populate.  So if you're writing unit tests, you could do it in your `[Setup]` or `[TestInitialize]` method.

Answer (score 3):

NBuilder is pretty nice.

I believe it uses reflection as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/) makes a tool called [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/).  If you are willing to use a database as a seed for your testing objects, I think you'll find it is a pretty flexible tool.

Answer (score 2):

```
PM> Install-Package NBuilder
```

note: EducationInformation class itself have lots of string properties

```
var rootObject = new RootObject()
            {
                EducationInformation = Builder<EducationInformation>.CreateNew().Build(),
                PersonalInformation = Builder<PersonalInformation>.CreateNew().Build(),
                PositionsInformation = Builder<PositionsInformation>.CreateNew().Build()                    
            };
```

sample final JSON output: all with property name and a number

```
"graduateDegree":"graduateDegree1","academicDiscipline":"academicDiscipline1"
```

note: i do not know why using the  following command returns null for all internal classes

```
RootObject rootObject = Builder<RootObject>.CreateNew().Build()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **.NET**, you can use [FakeItEasy](https://fakeiteasy.github.io/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy)), a free and open-source .NET dynamic fake framework.

And it's compatible with .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Since some libraries are either a bit outdated or no longer under development, I have created my own library [Oxygenize](https://github.com/kamil-mrzyglod/Oxygenize), which enables you to populate classes with either random or customized data.

Answer (score 0):

[RandomPOCOGenerator](https://github.com/Jpinsoft/RandomPOCOGenerator) is a simple reflection-based tool designed for generating and populating objects with random values

```
[TestMethod]
public void GenerateTest()
{
   RPGenerator gen = new RPGenerator();
   int maxRecursionLevel = 4;

   var intRes = gen.Generate<int>(maxRecursionLevel);            
   var stringArrayRes = gen.Generate<string[]>(maxRecursionLevel);
   var charArrayRes = gen.Generate<char[]>(maxRecursionLevel);
   var pocoRes = gen.Generate<SamplePocoClass>(maxRecursionLevel);
   var structRes = gen.Generate<SampleStruct>(maxRecursionLevel);
   var pocoArray = gen.Generate<SamplePocoClass[]>(maxRecursionLevel);
   var listRes = gen.Generate<List<SamplePocoClass>>(maxRecursionLevel);
   var dictRes = gen.Generate<Dictionary<string, List<List<SamplePocoClass>>>>(maxRecursionLevel);
   var parameterlessList = gen.Generate<List<Tuple<string, int>>>(maxRecursionLevel);

   // Non-generic Generate
   var stringArrayRes = gen.Generate(typeof(string[]), maxRecursionLevel);
   var pocoRes = gen.Generate(typeof(SamplePocoClass), maxRecursionLevel);
   var structRes = gen.Generate(typeof(SampleStruct), maxRecursionLevel);

   Trace.WriteLine("-------------- TEST Results ------------------------");
   Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("TotalCountOfGeneratedObjects {0}", gen.TotalCountOfGeneratedObjects));
   Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Generating errors            {0}", gen.Errors.Count));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy and clean:

```
public static void populateObject( object o)
    {
        Random r = new Random ();
        FieldInfo[] propertyInfo = o.GetType().GetFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < propertyInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            FieldInfo info = propertyInfo[i];

            string strt = info.FieldType.Name;
            Type t = info.FieldType;
            try
            {
                dynamic value = null;

                if (t == typeof(string) || t == typeof(String))
                {
                    value = "asdf";
                }
                else if (t == typeof(Int16) || t == typeof(Int32) || t == typeof(Int64))
                {
                    value = (Int16)r.Next(999);
                    info.SetValue(o, value);
                }
                else if (t == typeof(Int16?))
                {
                    Int16? v = (Int16)r.Next(999);
                    info.SetValue(o, v);
                }
                else if (t == typeof(Int32?))
                {
                    Int32? v = (Int32)r.Next(999);
                    info.SetValue(o, v);
                }
                else if (t == typeof(Int64?))
                {
                    Int64? v = (Int64)r.Next(999);
                    info.SetValue(o, v);
                }
                else if (t == typeof(DateTime) || t == typeof(DateTime?))
                {
                    value = DateTime.Now;
                    info.SetValue(o, value);
                }
                else if (t == typeof(double) || t == typeof(float) || t == typeof(Double))
                {
                    value = 17.2;
                    info.SetValue(o, value);
                }
                else if (t == typeof(char) || t == typeof(Char))
                {
                    value = 'a';
                    info.SetValue(o, value);
                }
                else
                {
                    //throw new NotImplementedException ("Tipo não implementado :" + t.ToString () );
                    object temp = info.GetValue(o);
                    if (temp == null)
                    {
                        temp = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                        info.SetValue(o, temp);
                    }
                    populateObject(temp);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP wanted a library.  perhaps you should revise your answer