# Dummy ObjectList generator for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dummy-data

Can anyone inform whether there is any good framework in c# that will generate dummy objects and lists so that we don't need to generate the stub data manually?

Answer (score 6):

You can try [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/). It's purpose is rapid generation of test objects.

If you have Employee class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

Generating list of 10 Employee object is simple like this:

```
var employees = Builder<Employee>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build();
```

It will generate unique incremental values for all fields of object:

```
Name1 7/12/2012
Name2 7/13/2012
Name3 7/14/2012
...
```

Also NBuilder has nice powerful fluent interface, which allows to setup custom values for any generated object:

```
var employees = Builder<Employee>.CreateListOfSize(10)
    .TheFirst(1).With(e => e.Name = "Sergey")
    .All().With(e => e.Address = Builder<Address>.CreateNew().Build())
    .Build();
```

Also you can take a look at:

- [Autofixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/)
- [AutoPoco](http://autopoco.codeplex.com/)
- [Symply Test Data](http://igor-toporet.github.com/simply-test-data/)

Answer (score 1):

The framework I like to use and does what you ask is the following: [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/blog/3384/rhino-mocks-3-5-design-decisions-the-role-of-stub-vs-mock)

This is for C#, and its superior.

Answer (score 0):

The framework I like to use and does what you ask is the following: [Unitils](http://unitils.org/summary.html)

but then again, I don't know for which programming language you are asking ? The one proposed is for Java.

Comment: I was looking for something in C#. Is there any?

Comment: Sadly I don't know anything about the C# language sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create fake implementations of interfaces or abstract classes then there's a bunch of "mocking frameworks" available. One of them is Rhimo Mocks mentioned by Harry. For you as a beginner in this area I'd also suggest [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) as it's more straightforward compared to Rhino Mocks (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Everyone likes realistic fake data, use [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) library.

> ```
> var faker = new Faker("en");
>
> var emailList = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
>       .Select(_ => faker.Internet.Email())
>       .ToList();
>
> //OUTPUT:
> Gustave83@hotmail.com    
> Evie33@gmail.com 
> Abby_Wilkinson@yahoo.com 
> Cecilia.Hahn@yahoo.com   
> Jasen.Waelchi85@gmail.com
> ```